# javascript exception "unexpected token o"

Tags: javascript

I have json data like this :

```
   {
    "count": 5,
    "min_tanggal": "2014-03-14 00:00:00",
    "items": [{
        "id": "4",
        "publish": "Ya",
        "tanggal": "2014-03-19 00:00:00",
        "dibuat": "2014-03-23 16:33:34",
        "diubah": "2014-03-23 16:43:22",
        "penulis": "Sepriyono Humas",
        "id_kategori": "1",
        "kategori_berita": "Umum",
        "isi": "<p>Kerinci - Bupati Kerinci Pimpin Upacara Peringatan Hari Bakti Rimbawan tahun 2014 yang di gelar di halaman Kantor Bupati Kerinci senen (17\/03),Peringatan Hari Bakti Rimbawan juga diikuti oleh sejumlah Kepala SKPD dalam lingkup Pemkab Kerinci.<\/p>\r",
        "tanggal_format": "Rabu, 19 Maret 2014",
        "href": ".\/?page=berita&id=4"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "publish": "Ya",
        "tanggal": "2014-03-17 00:00:00",
        "dibuat": "2014-03-23 16:35:19",
        "diubah": "2014-03-23 17:43:20",
        "penulis": "Sepriyono Humas",
        "id_kategori": "1",
        "kategori_berita": "Umum",
        "isi": "<p>Kerinci - Lima Misi Adzan untuk mewujudkan pembangunan Kerinci yang lebih baik kedepan, Lima Misi tersebut akan diselaraskan dengan Program Pembangunan yang ada di APBD 2014, Misi ini sangat perlu diketahui oleh masyarakat Kerinci agar masyarakat",
        "tanggal_format": "Senin, 17 Maret 2014",
        "href": ".\/?page=berita&id=5"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "publish": "Ya",
        "tanggal": "2014-03-17 00:00:00",
        "dibuat": "2014-03-23 16:36:35",
        "diubah": "2014-03-23 17:43:31",
        "penulis": "Sepriyono Humas",
        "id_kategori": "1",
        "kategori_berita": "Umum",
        "isi": "<p>Kerinci - Bupati Kerinci H. Adirozal menyerahkan penghargaan kepada pemenang Pelaku PNPM-MPd Kabupaten Kerinci tahun 2014, penyerahan tersebut dilaksanakan usai Upacara Senen ( 17\/03) yang bertempat di Halaman Kantor Bupati Kerinci.<\/p>\r",
        "tanggal_format": "Senin, 17 Maret 2014",
        "href": ".\/?page=berita&id=6"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "publish": "Ya",
        "tanggal": "2014-03-17 00:00:00",
        "dibuat": "2014-03-23 16:37:41",
        "diubah": "2014-03-23 17:43:50",
        "penulis": "bappeda",
        "id_kategori": "1",
        "kategori_berita": "Umum",
        "isi": "<p>Dalam upaya mempercepat terwujudnya pembangunan Kerinci yang lebih baik Bupati Kerinci Dr. H Adirozal, M.Si Bersama Wakil Bupati Kerinci Zainal Abidin SH, MM, langsung membuka acara Musrenbang RKPD Kabupaten Kerinci.<\/p>\r",
        "tanggal_format": "Senin, 17 Maret 2014",
        "href": ".\/?page=berita&id=7"
    }, {
        "id": "8",
        "publish": "Ya",
        "tanggal": "2014-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dibuat": "2014-03-23 16:39:25",
        "diubah": "2014-03-23 17:44:01",
        "penulis": "Sepriyono Humas",
        "id_kategori": "1",
        "kategori_berita": "Umum",
        "isi": "<p>Kerinci - Pasangan Bupati dan Wakil Bupati Kerinci yang baru saja dilantik bertekad untuk mewujudkan Kerinci menjadi lebih baik kedepan, pasalnya pasangan ini akan terus bertekad menjadi pelayan Masyarakat dan bekerja untuk kepentingan",
        "tanggal_format": "Jumat, 14 Maret 2014",
        "href": ".\/?page=berita&id=8"
    }]
}
```

javascript:

```
success: function(e) {
   var data = $.parseJSON(e);
}
```

why return error "unexpected token o", please help me...

Comment: Maybe before asking, try some basic troubleshooting, like `console.log(e)`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess Your data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you.

```
success: function(e) {
   alert(e['count']);
 }
```

Comment: does it solve your problem @Yosa?